# Meta Algorithm for Finite State Machine. How to fix error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects?

Tags: python

```
alphabet = open('alphabet.txt', 'r')
finalStates = open('finalStates.txt', 'r')
startState = open('startState.txt', 'r')
states = open('states.txt', 'r')
transitionTable = open('transitionTable.txt', 'r')

start = startState.readline()
curState = start[1]
final = finalStates.readline()
finalState = final[1]

import sys
input = sys.argv[1]
i = 0    

for c in input:
    while True:
        pirate = transitionTable.readline()
        if not pirate: break
        value = 2
        index = pirate[value]
        if (curState == index and input[i] == (index + 4)):
            curState = pirate[index + 9]
            if(curState == finalState):
                print ('accept')
        value = value + 13
        i = i + 1
```

Here is my code that uses 5 files and a string from the command line and runs them through a finite state machine and returns accept or reject. At `if(curState == index and input[0] == (index + 4)):` is where my error occurs because im assuming the `input` from the command line is a string and cant be compared to type int of `(index + 4)` from the transitiontable.txt file. However I tried converting them to be the same type and it didnt work and dont know how to move forward.

the transitiontable file is in this format:
"q0","b","q1"
"q0","a","NULL"
and so on with the first state then the char that is tested and the state it would then move to.

Comment: "index = pirate[value]" is not going to assign a number to "index", it will instead grab the character at the "value" position from the string that "pirate" contains. If that position really is an index, you'll want to convert it to an integer after.

Comment: @Iain I tried that, index = int(pirate[value]), but then i revceive the error "string index out of range"

Comment: Ah. Don't forget that strings and arrays are zero-indexed -- so the first character of the string will be at 0, the second at 1, and so on. Also, you may want to look carefully at "== (index + 4)" I don't think that will do as you intend it to.